# Text overlaying image inside a div with a background image?

Tags: css

Is there any way to get the image in between `section` and the text? So I want the background for `section` at the lowest layer, then the image, then the text overlaying the image. I tried messing around with `z-index` but I couldn't get it to work. If I take out `section` and the background for it, [it works as it should](http://jsfiddle.net/y9ywL1gx/2/). But that `section` tag has to be there to serve as the background for that section.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9ywL1gx/1/

HTML

```
<section>
    <div class="block">
        <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

        <img src="http://img2.tvtome.com/i/u/ac51b5ad45b24475c4667f74aefdc9a5.png">

    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
    background: url("http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/symphony.png") repeat;
}
div.block {
    position: relative;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

To clarify, right now it's: `south park image --> section background --> text`. I want it to be: `section background --> south park image --> text`

Comment: *`So I want the background for section at the lowest layer, then the image, then the...`* I'm lost in translation

Comment: @Roko I want section at the lowest z index, then the image should be on top of the section, then the text should be at the very top overlaying the image.

Comment: Ok, but your text is overflowing the south-park image bro! what about it?

Comment: It's not here: http://jsfiddle.net/y9ywL1gx/1/ I don't want that section background to be there (the white textured bg). It should be under the south park image.

Comment: aaaahahh got it! But any way,,, what about the text exceeding the s-p image width?

Comment: Ok, right now it's: `south park image --> section background --> text`. I want it to be: `section background --> south park image --> text`

Comment: @Roko It's the way I need it set up on my website. I can also put the white textured background as the body background which would work, but I can't do it like that in my case.

Comment: :) in your CSS you're targeting always `div class="block"` ignoring that actually your text is inside an inner `DIV` ;) Target him! (see my example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you seem to want: http://jsfiddle.net/y9ywL1gx/5/

Try to reorder the elements instead of using `z-index`.

Comment: Is there any way to *not* use `position: absolute` on `.block`? I have multiple `.block` divs on my site and I can't have them all positioned absolutely.

Comment: You can position it relatively. http://jsfiddle.net/y9ywL1gx/12/

Also, an element can be assigned to multiple classes. So, separating it from other `.block`s should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/y9ywL1gx/9/)***

Simply in your HTML set your image **before** the inner `div` and don't use `z-index: -1;`!!

```
<section>
    <div class="block">        
        <img src="south.png"/>       <!-- respect natural Z- order -->
        <div>Lorem Ipsum.</div>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section   { background: url("pattern.png"); }
.block div{ position: absolute; top:0; }
```

<sub>Note: if you want the inner image to kiss-top use</sub>

```
.block img{ vertical-align:middle; }
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it so that `.block div` doesn't have to be positioned absolutely? The reason is because on my website, I have multiple `.block` divs that naturally fall one right after the other so I can't position them absolutely.

Comment: @J82 only by setting the s-park image as the .block element background-image.